# NSManagedObjectContext performBlock within dispatch_async

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, grand-central-dispatch, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm doing some background processing with GCD and saving some objects with Core Data. In method `[self saveData]` I'm creating a `NSManagedObjectContext` with concurrency type `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` to perform the Core Data operations on a background thread. I'm running all my Core Data operations within `performBlock`.

Now, is it necessary to call `[self saveData]` from main thread or can I continue in the background thread I'm in (to avoid the extra call `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});`)

Like so:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{

    BOOL isProcessed = [self processData];
    if (isProcessed) {

        // Save with Core Data
        [self saveData];
    }
});
```

Or do I need to do:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{

    BOOL isProcessed = [self processData];
    if (isProcessed) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            // Save with Core Data
            [self saveData];
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`performBlock:` and `performBlockAndWait:` ensure that the block operations are executed on the queue specified for the context. Therefore, it does not matter on which thread `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:` are called.

The extra `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});` is therefore not necessary if `[self saveData]` uses `performBlock:` for all operations.

Comment: How about if the app quits before the save completes?   Apple suggests not saving in background: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html

Comment: @danh: The [Core Data Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/_index.html) explicitly mention the use of nested managed object contexts for performing background operations on a second thread, and "saving" in this case would mean that the changes are "committed one store up". The new concurrency types and nested contexts are not yet covered in the "Core Data Programming Guide". I have only tried to answer the question if `dispatch_async` is required here.

Comment: @danh: (cont.) But apart from that, that is a good point that one should consider!

Comment: @danh I think SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596087/saving-core-data-in-a-thread-how-to-ensure-its-done-writing-before-quitting applies rather well to your question, I think that is the approach I will consider in my app. BTW, thanks for quick answer Martin.

Comment: @PeterWarbo: That question/answer was written before nested contexts and the new concurrency types existed. And I think the usage of a private queue MOC for saving data was mentioned in some WWDC session. - So the question is whether "Saving in a Background Thread is Error-prone" applies also to the new private queue MOCs - I don't know!

Comment: @MartinR I would assume that is still the case unless anything else states it isn't. And when you think of it, any operations in a background thread will be left in a "freeze-dried" state when app moves into background so for a Core Data managed queue that behavior should be identical.